# Use a template to get alternate behaviour?

Tags: c++, templates, bad-code

Is this a bad practice?

```
const int sId(int const id);

// true/false it doesn't matter
template<bool i>
const int sId(int const id) {
    return this->id = id;
}
```

```
const int MCard::sId(int const id){
    MCard card = *this;

    this->id = id;

    this->onChange.fire(EventArgs<MCard&, MCard&>(*this, card));

    return this->id;
}
```

```
myCard.sId(9);

myCard.sId<true>(8);
```

As you can see, my goal is to be able to have an alternative behaviour for sId.

I know I could use a second parameter to the function and use a if, but this feels more fun (imo) and might prevent branch prediction (I'm no expert in that field).

So, is it a valid practice, and/or is there a better approach?

Comment: This would warrant a WTF moment in code review for me.  I see what you're going for, and I sympathize your cause.  That said, don't do it.

Comment: Why not just two functions: `sId()` and `sIdTrue()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, it seems you are just overcomplicating things, which might obfuscate your code. This

```
sId
```

and this

```
sId<true>
```

are just two different functions. And the standard way of implementing two different functions (with the same signature) is simply to use two different function names, without the template hoodoo voodoo, like `sIdWithoutEvent` and `sId` (assumed the latter one is  calling the event).